# Property of Normal Subgroups under Special Conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G = MN$. Show that for any $m \in M$ and $n \in N$, we can find elements $m' \in M, n' \in N$ such that $mn' = nm'$.

I've tried using properties of normal subgroups (i.e. $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$), but I can't seem to relate m directly with n in the desired form. Any hints?

Comment: We can write $n^{-1} m n = m'$ where $m' \in M$ because $M$ is normal. Multiplying both sides on the left by $n$ gives us $mn = nm'$. This shows that we can in fact take $n' = n$. Moreover, we don't need both subgroups to be normal. Normality of $M$ suffices. You can make a similar argument if only $N$ is assumed normal.

Comment: By the way, the result is true even if neither $M$ nor $N$ is normal. All that is required is that $G = MN$ or, more generally, that $MN$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need inverses, it's easier to write $m'=m_1$ and $n'=n_1$. The relation you want can be rewritten
$$
m^{-1}n=n_1m_1^{-1}
$$
Now
$$
m^{-1}n=m^{-1}nmm^{-1}
$$
so you can take $n_1=m^{-1}nm$ and $m_1=m$.